# Magento 2.4.6 ScandiPWA displaying blank page in the frontend?

Tags: magento2, pwa, magento2.4.6, pwa-theme, scandipwa

i have installed ScandiPWA theme in existing magento 2.4.6 to follows the below steps.

Install Fresh Magento 2.4.6 with php version 8.1

Step 1 : go to magento root and create the src/localmodules directory

**mkdir src**

**mkdir localmodules**

step 2 : go to src/localmodules and run the below command to setup magento storefront as per user guide.

**cd src/localmodules**

url : https://docs.scandipwa.com/getting-started-1/storefront-mode

**npx create-scandipwa-app pwatheme**

-->commmand run successfully after go to pwatheme directory and run the below command.

**npm start**

step 3 : npm build successfully after go to magento root and run the below command to install scandipwa in magento

Url : https://docs.scandipwa.com/getting-started-1/magento-integration

**composer config repo.theme path src/localmodules/pwatheme**

**composer require scandipwa/pwatheme**

after composer install theme to run magento upgrade command.

Step 4 : setup persisted-query using the below command.

```
php bin/magento setup:config:set --pq-host=127.0.0.1 --pq-port=6379 --pq-scheme="tcp" --pq-database=5
```

step 5 : After setup persisted-query run the below magento command.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento cache:disable full_page
```

Step 6 : Change Magento theme to ScandiPWA in magento content configuration.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ft7UI.png

**Magento Admin panel  > Content > Configuration**

i have follows this steps after show frontend shows blank page.please check the attached screenshot.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwgvp.png

Comment: I have found the solution for blank page showing. this is our local domain related issue.i have created subdomain in my local server and configure in magento base url after check it is working